# Separable Differential Equation $9x - 4y\sqrt{x^2 + 1} \frac{dy}{dx} = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the separable differential equation:
>   $$9x - 4y\sqrt{x^2 + 1} \frac{dy}{dx} = 0$$
>   Subject to the initial condition:  $y(0) = −3$.

This particular situation looks like it can be solves by moving the $x$ to the other side of the equation:

$$4y\sqrt{x^2 + 1} \frac{dy}{dx} = 9x$$
$$4y \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{9x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}$$

Then we can integrate with respect to $x$:

$$4\int y\frac{dy}{dx} \, dx = \int \frac{9x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}} \, dx$$

which, by canceling $dx$ and integrating the left hand side by $y$ and the right hand side by $x$, we have that:

$$4 \frac{y^2}{2} + C_1 = 9\sqrt{x^2 + 1} + C_2$$
$$2y^2 = 9\sqrt{x^2 + 1} + C$$

which, given the initial condition $y(0) = −3$:

$$C = 2(-3)^2 - 9\sqrt{1} = 18 - 9 = 9$$

So finally:

$$y = \sqrt{\frac{9\sqrt{x^2 + 1} + 9}{2}}$$

But sadly this is not the correct answer. Where am I going wrong with this process? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: At least you have forgotten the minus sign befor the square root.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: Actually, I don't really see how that error was introduced. Moving $9x$ over makes everything in the equation positive. The initial condition is also squared.

Comment: You find $y^2=\dots$. Thus, in principle, there are two possible values of $y$. You write $y=\sqrt{\dots}$, but this is wrong, because then $y$ is positive, while your initial condition is negative. So you should take $y=-\sqrt{\dots}$ instead.

Comment: Sorry but why did you feel you had to accept an answer which does not even touch the question you are actually asking (as opposed to @Vladimir's two comments above, for example)?

Comment: You're probably right. @Vladimir addressed the real issue I was having, but the accepted answer was a formalized way to get there. If he makes an answer, I would accept it.

Comment: If @Vladimir does not, you may post an answer yourself.